# File Allocation for VM

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I'm running Kali Linux as a virtual machine inside Oracle's Virtualbox. I've allocated 40GB of hard drive space, file type: VirtualBox Disk Image; Dynamicallly Allocated. On the VM it is showing the 40Gb under SATA Controller, Port 0.

Now here is the problem, in Kali, the file system only has 2.3Gb of free space remaining, filling up with the first update basically. The Contents section, goes to 1.7TB and keeps climbing... my largest HD is only 1 TB and its a external USB HD.

I've uninstalled and re-installed multiple times, trying different configurations according to various methods. I've been searching and reading online including this magic partition-er thing, not sure if that actually works; it doesn't even show me a partition.

I'm new to Linux, Kali especially, learning as I go, but this ones got me stumped. I just cant seam to find the right answer for my issue, or maybe I'm over looking the obvious?

Comment: Maybe I'm over looking the obvious, but: what is your question?  That your Kali VM fills its disk quickly?  Have you tried recreating the VM with more disk?  And what are you saying about a 1 TB disk with 1.7 TB contents?

Comment: G.man,  sorry, new to this, but yes ... my disk space gets used up fast, despite being set at 60 GB, I dont know what its set at in the software, but after installation, nothing else, I have 2.7Gb of free space, Surely Kali linux installed isnt 58Gb, right?

Comment: Best way I can describe this is when installing, Im selecting 40Gb for hard drive space, going into kali, under file system properties, on the Basic Tab ... Contents: 749697 Items,  Totalling 140.7 TB ( I have 1.5TB including external hard drive ), Location: Computer:///, Volume: Unknown,  Free Space 2.3GB. none of this makes any sense to me lol, how can I have 140TB used space, when I dont even have 1.5?